# Name for a probability density ''symmetrized'' by a permutation group?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, pr.probability

Let $p$ be a probability density function over random variable $X$, and $G$ a compact permutation group over the outcomes of $X$.  For each $g\in G$, let $p_g$ indicate the probability density function of the random variable $g(X)$.  Now, imagine that one "symmetrizes" $p$ by mixing together the densities induced by each $g\in G$,
$$
\tilde{p}(x)=\int_G p_g(x)\; d\mu 
$$
where $\mu$ indicates the Haar measure of $G$. Is there a name/reference describing such an operation?

Comment: conditional expectation over the $G$-invariant sigma-algebra?